# How to find a smoothed curve joining a set of points (in Open CV)?

Tags: c++, opencv, filtering, convolution, smoothing

I want to remove noise in a curve. What I have as a set of points ( `std::vector<Point>` ). This represents a curve, but it's noisy. So I want remove the noise and get a smooth curve.

I've tried several options like **polynomial curve fitting** and `cv::approxPolyDP`. But they don't give what I want.

Now I want to smooth it using filtering. But in opencv the functions are for images (2D signals). So how can I do it for a 1D signal like this ?

Comment: So, you have using cv::Point structure for a 1D signal?

Comment: You can have an image with only one row. Convolution will work just fine in this case.

Comment: @scap3y : what i have is a set of data points ( vector of cv::Points ). So we can look at it as Point.x being the independent variable and Point.y being the dependent variable or vise versa. In that sense it is a 1D signal. Isn't it ?

Comment: @berak : Kalman Filter is a good suggestion. Actually it should work. I'll try it.

Comment: @Geoff : since the gaps between the data points are not the same, we might need to interpolate in between the data points to get it equally spaced. Otherwise we can't put it in to a single row image, isn't it so?

Comment: You might want to use convolution using a Gaussian/Bilateral kernel. A smoothing spline will most likely end up corrupting the useful data.

Comment: OP, what does your data actually _look_ like? You could use `cv::circle(...)` to draw your points onto some image (probably a blank white image) to make a quick scatter plot. (You can also draw connecting line segments using `cv::line(...)`. This would tell us the order your points are in, which might be important.) If you could then also hand-draw on top of that (eg, using Paint) what you would like the output to be, we would have a much clearer idea what you are after.

Comment: @Optimus - Yes, that could be an important consideration in your case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is as [smoothing spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline).

> The smoothing spline is a method of smoothing (fitting a smooth curve to a set of noisy observations) using a spline function.

Unfortunately, I don't think this is already implemented in OpenCV. Nevertheless, a bit of quick Googling turned up that the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) includes support for [basis smoothing splines](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Basis-Splines.html#Basis-Splines), which seems like it will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I want to do it only using opencv.

Comment: @Optimus Any particular reason for limiting yourself to OpenCV? It sounds like you might be getting sucked into the "I have a hammer, so everything looks like a nail" mindset. I would advise you to find/use the right tool for the job.